# Number of sessions in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 2.
Session is created by Symfony2 whenever user login is successful.

Is there way to get the count of active session?

Do I have to write any code to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in symfony2 to do this. You will have to build custom logic to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you write "lastLoginDate" to database, you could try to use this to estimate, how many users logged in the last hours. In addition, you could check the "session.gc_maxlifetime" php.ini setting to know how long a php session stays alive.

this post is also nice to read
http://www.symfony-grenoble.fr/en/238/list-online-users/